# Microsoft Blend 2022 Community Edition - Cant find pen

Tags: blend

Hi I am new to microsoft blend. I am trying to find the pen in Microsoft Blend to draw custom shapes but I can't seem to find it as in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/draw-shapes-and-paths?view=vs-2022
or
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32741.microsoft-blend-for-visual-studio-uwp-creating-a-simple-animation.aspx

Here is the what I see in my ide:

[microsoft blend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOipY.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're editing a UWP project. I had the same experience with Blend  2019 and Blend 2022. I found that you can find the pen and pencil if you create and edit a WPF project; you could therefore create your graphic "paths" in WPF, and later copy them to UWP. (the UWP "designer" hasn't caught up, in other words)